# Foreach in Smarty

Tags: smarty

My smarty `{brands}` has returns this array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '98' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Adidas' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '168' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Agisko' (length=6)
```

I need, that this views all `name` from array. How Can I write this is in smarty?

```
<ul>
    {foreach $brands as $brand}
    <li>{$brands|var_dump}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associative array values can be accessed as you would in PHP code, or using dot notation:

```
<ul>
    {foreach $brands as $brand}
        <li>{$brand['name']}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>

<ul>
    {foreach $brands as $brand}
        <li>{$brand.name}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```